# Bootstrap change mobile navbar from middle to top-right corner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I had downloaded a bootstrap template which has a dropdown menu in middle(mobile version).

Like this:
http://postimg.org/image/58hmpb8f5/

But i want dropdown menu on the top-right corner of my mobile screen

Like this : http://postimg.org/image/5fkeraou1/

This is my html code so far:

```
<header id ="top" class="mTop">
    <div class="topHead">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="topMenu">
                    <ul class="span12 topContact">
                        <li class="addresTop"><span class="icon-map-marker"></span>456 Jl.Pacar, Singapore</li>
                        <li class="mailTop"><span class="icon-envelope"></span>Office@Plasma.com</li>
                        <li class="phoneTop"><span class="icon-phone"></span>(+1) 321-9876520</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="headContent">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="brand">
                        <a href=""><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span8">
                    <div class="menu" id="steak">
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="navMenu inline-list" id="nav"> 
                                <li class="current"><a href="#top">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#team">Our Team</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont you want to use the latest boostrap instead? the latest bootstrap which is 3.3.1 has the navigation that you need.

code in bs3.3.1 is something like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

for bootstrap 2, the basic navigation where in you will have a top right menu in mobile view will be

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
      <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anyway to do this same stuff in Bootstrap 2.
I don't want to update my whole html right now.

Comment: i see, well just modify the code you have on the dropdown to be - let me update my answer